# Terminology: A user-defined function object attribute?

Tags: python, oop, methods, language-lawyer, terminology

According to Python 2.7.12 documentation, [User-defined methods](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> User-defined method objects may be created when getting an attribute
>   of a class (perhaps via an instance of that class), if that attribute
>   is a **user-defined function object, an unbound user-defined method
>   object, or a class method object**. When the attribute is a
>   user-defined method object, a new method object is only created if the
>   class from which it is being retrieved is the same as, or a derived
>   class of, the class stored in the original method object; otherwise,
>   the original method object is used as it is.

I know that everything in Python is an object, so a "user-defined method" must be identical to a "user-defined method *object*". However, I can't understand why there is a "user-defined function object attribute". Say, in the following code:

```
class Foo(object):
    def meth(self):
       pass
```

`meth` is a function defined inside a class body, and thus a [method](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html). So why can we have a "user-defined function object attribute"? Aren't all attributes defined inside a class body?

---

**Bouns question:** Provide some examples illustrating how a user-defined method object is *created* by *getting* an attribute of a class. Isn't objects *defined* in their class definition? (I know methods can be assigned to a class instance, but that's monkey patching.)

I'm asking for help because this part of document is really really confusing to me, a programmer who only knows C, since Python is such a magical language that supports both functional programming and object-oriented programmer, which I haven't mastered yet. I've done a lot of search, but still can't figure that out.

Comment: Thanks for asking this, trying to understand this for like an hour

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do

```
class Foo(object):
    def meth(self):
       pass
```

you are defining a class `Foo` with a method `meth`. However, when this class definition is executed, no method object is created to represent the method. The `def` statement creates an ordinary function object.

If you then do

```
Foo.meth
```

or

```
Foo().meth
```

the attribute lookup finds the function object, but the function object is not used as the value of the attribute. Instead, using the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), Python calls the `__get__` method of the function object to construct a method object, and that method object is used as the value of the attribute for that lookup. For `Foo.meth`, the method object is an unbound method object, which behaves like the function you defined, but with an extra type checking of `self`. For `Foo().meth`, the method object is a bound method object, which already knows what `self` is.

---

This is why `Foo().meth()` doesn't complain about a missing `self` argument; you pass 0 arguments to the method object, which then prepends `self` to the (empty) argument list and passes the arguments on to the underlying function object. If `Foo().meth` evaluated to the `meth` function directly, you would have to pass it `self` explicitly.

---

In Python 3, `Foo.meth` doesn't create an unbound method object; the function's `__get__` still gets called, but it returns the function directly, [since Guido decided unbound method objects weren't useful](https://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/02/first-class-everything.html). `Foo().meth` still creates a bound method object, though.

Comment: The quotation also said "When the attribute is a user-defined method object, ……" But how can an class attribution be a _user-defined method object_ instead of an _ordinary function object_?

Comment: Extra question: Could you provide an example illustrating the difference between a **class from which it is being retrieved** and a **class stored in the original method object**?

Comment: @sunqingyao: `class Foo(object): def method(self): pass`, `class Bar(object): method = Foo.method`. Now the `Bar` class has an unbound method object in its dict, and that unbound method records that it came from the `Foo` class.

Comment: And if `class Foo(object): def method(self): pass; method2 = Foo.method` is the case in which "the class from which it is being retrieved is the same as the class stored in the original method object"?

Comment: @sunqingyao: Close. `Foo` doesn't exist yet inside the body of the class statement, so you'd have to do something like `Foo.method = Foo.method` after the class statement completes.